back-propagation calculations notation and the average constant
$$J = -\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(y^{(i)}log(a^{[L](i)}) + (1-y^{(i)})y^{(i)}log(1-a^{[L](i)})$$
For the last layer, I saw that $$dA^{[L]} = - (\frac{Y}{A^{[L]}} - \frac{1-Y}{1 - A^{[L]}})$$
My question is why $dA^{[L]}$ does not include the $\frac{1}{m}$ in front of it?
My intuition was $$dA^{[L]} = [\frac{\partial J}{\partial a^{[L](1)}}, \frac{\partial J}{\partial a^{[L](2)}}, \dots,\frac{\partial J}{\partial a^{[L](m)}}]$$
and
$$\frac{\partial J}{\partial a^{[L](i)}} = -\frac{1}{m} (\frac{y^{(i)}}{a^{[L](i)}} - \frac{1-y^{(i)}}{1-a^{[L](i)}})$$
after vectorization
$$dA^{[L]} = -\frac{1}{m} (\frac{Y}{A^{[L]}} - \frac{1-Y}{1 - A^{[L]}})$$
Could anybody tell me what's wrong going on here? Thanks!
In addition, I saw $dW^{[l]} = \frac{1}{m}dZ^{[l]}A^{[l-1]T}$, $db^{[l]}=\frac{1}{m}\sum_i dZ^{[l](i)}$, and $dA^{[l-1]} = W^{[l]T}dZ^{[l]}$. Why do dW and db include the 1/m, but not the dA?

We are averaging over the $m$ training examples when calculating the gradient of $dW$ and $db$,
While $dA$ is the derivative of the cost with respect to $A$. $dA$ is one piece of the gradient calculation for $dW$ and $db$.
An easier way to understand this is to look at the differentiation of the cost function of the non vectorized version.
$$J = -\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(y^{(i)}log(a^{[L](i)}) + (1-y^{(i)})y^{(i)}log(1-a^{[L](i)})
$$
Let $$ L( \hat{y} , a) = (y^{(i)}log(a^{[L](i)}) + (1-y^{(i)})y^{(i)}log(1-a^{[L](i)})$$
Then we have
$$J = -\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m} L( y^{(i)} , a^{(i)})$$
If we take the derivative with respect to $W$
$$\frac{\partial J}{\partial W} =  \frac{\partial}{\partial W}  \biggl\{ -\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m} L( y^{(i)} , a^{(i)}) \biggl\}
$$
We can then move the differential operator into the sum
$$\frac{\partial J}{\partial W} =    -\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m} \frac{\partial}{\partial W} L( y^{(i)} , a^{(i)})$$
We can then calculate the derivate of L with respect to W using the chain rule - for simplicity, I am assuming a 1 layer Neural Network
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial W} L( y^{(i)} , a^{(i)}) = \frac{\partial L}{\partial a} \frac{\partial a}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial w}$$
We then get
$$\frac{\partial J}{\partial W} =    -\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m} \frac{\partial L}{\partial a} \frac{\partial a}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial w}$$
The key thing to note is the $-\frac{1}{m}$ is on the outside and applied after the derivative is calculated.
A similar reasoning can be applied when calculating the the gradients in the vectorized version.

Thank you! But I am still confusing about why dA does not include the 1/m. What's wrong with my process above?

In this calculation - dA is the derivative of the inside function (in terms of the chain rule). For example, consider the following function: $\frac{1}{m}L(a(x))$. If we were to take it's derivative, per the chain rule, the derivative of the outside function is $\frac{1}{m}L'(a(x))$ and the derivative of the inside function is $a'(x)$ and not $\frac{1}{m}a'(x)$, the $\frac{1}{m}$ constant is part of the outside function. Hence, dA would not have the constant term -hope this helps!

If $J = \frac{1}{m}L$, do you mean $dA = \frac{dL}{da}$ instead $dA = \frac{dJ}{da}$? In this case, dA does not include the 1/m term. However, why does dW and db are the derivatives of J respect to the W or b?

If you have a function; $f(g(x))$ and want to find $\frac{df}{dx}$, the chain rule states:  $\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x)) = f'(g(x))g'(x)$, this can also be written as $\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{df}{dg}\frac{dg}{dx}$. So if $J(x) = \frac{1}{m}L(a(x))$ and you want to find $\frac{dJ}{dx}$, you will need $\frac{dJ}{da}$ and $\frac{da}{dx}$. In some of the Deep Learning material online - https://cs230.stanford.edu/files/C1M3.pdf, $da$ is a short term notation for  $\frac{dJ}{da}$.  $W$ and $b$ are the parameters of the cost function that you are trying to estimate.

Thank you! Regarding W and b, I agree with the result above. But for the da, if da is $\frac{dJ}{da}$, then I think it should include the $1/m$ since $\frac{dJ}{da} = \frac{dJ}{dL}\frac{dL}{da}$ and $\frac{dJ}{dL} = -\frac{1}{m}$. Therefore,I am not sure if it's just a notation discrepancy here. $dW = \frac{dJ}{dL}\frac{dL}{da}\frac{da}{dW}$, and it includes the 1/m which was passed from da according to the chain rule, $dW = (da)\frac{da}{dW}$

Yes, it's a matter of  how your define your functions, for example, suppose you have $y = 2(1/x)^2$. You can solve this problem as $\frac{d}{dx} 2(1/x)^2$  or as  $2\frac{d}{dx}(1/x)^2$. You can then define the outside function with or without the 2, depending on if you pull the constant out of the differential operator. In the end, you will get the same answer.
